# VSCode is saying variables which use change using += 1 in python should be constants. Is this correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, constants

Here is an extremely simplified version of my code below:

```
foo = 0
bar = 0
baz = 0
while True:
    answer = input('Type an input here: ')
    print('And do something with it here.')
    if answer == 'okay':
        foo += 1
    else:
        bar += 1
    baz += 1
    print(foo, bar, baz)
```

When I save this, VSCode is giving me a warning saying:

> Constant name "foo" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style
>
> Constant name "foo" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style
>
> Constant name "foo" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style

My question is does the "+= 1" affect whether or not the variable should be a constant? I thought the "+= 1" would cause the variable to not be a constant as the variable changes, but VSCode is telling me otherwise.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151197/why-does-pylint-require-capitalized-variable-names-when-outside-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this problem:

[image]

Reason: According to the description of the [official pylint documentation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html), the reason for this warning is that Pylint's default constant naming style is uppercase:

```
"Naming style matching correct constant names.
Default: UPPER_CASE"
```

Therefore, Pylint’s warning is checked for "`foo = 0`, `bar = 0`, `baz = 0`", and for "`foo += 1` `bar += 1` `baz += 1`", Pylint does not give a warning, Pylint checks them as variables.

Solusion:Use the default uppercase name: FOO,BAR,BAZ.

[image]